# Laravel Elixir not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have some stylesheet and some scripts for admin panel and public files . I want to compile both with laravel elixir .

But Not working . Just compile admin styles and scripts . How can i do both ?

Here is my code:

```
    var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Less
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        'style.css',
        'select2.min.css',
        'redactor2.css',
        'custom.css'
        ], 'public/css/admin.css', 'resources/assets/css' )
    .styles([
        'css/bootstrap.css',
        'css/bootstrap-responsive.css',
        'css/jquery.smarticker.min.css',
        'css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css',
        'css/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css',
        'css/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css',
        'css/pstyle.css'
        ], 'public/css/public.css', 'resources/assets/css' );

    mix.scripts([
        'jquery.tools.min.js',
        'jquery-2.1.3.min.js',
        'jquery.leanModal.min.js',
        'jquery.form.js',
        'select2.min.js',
        'redactor2.js',
        'script.js',
        'plugin/fontcolor.js',
        'plugin/fontsize.js',
        'plugin/imagemanager.js',
        'plugin/table.js',
        'plugin/video.js'
    ], 'public/js/admin.js', 'resources/assets/js' )

    .scripts([
        'js/jquery.smarticker.min.js',
        'js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js',
        'js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js',
        'js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js',
        'js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js',
        'js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js',
        'js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
        'js/bootstrap.dropdown.min.js',
        'js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js',
        'js/public.js'
    ], 'public/js/public.js', 'resources/assets/js' );

    mix.version(['public/css/admin.css','public/css/public.css','public/js/admin.js','public/css/public.js']);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No error . Just compile one styles

Comment: remove the mix variables from scripts and version, just do `.scripts` and `.version`

Comment: after removing this error showing .. http://laravel.io/bin/Nkrow

Comment: you also have to remove the `;` after the second styles array

Comment: I have removed ; . But now no error showing . But same result as before. Just one styles and scripts are compiling .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution . I have made a mistake with my script . Please check http://laravel.io/bin/6LVEj

Thanks all for answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in cmd :

```
gulp --production && gulp version --production
```

Have the same bug on vagrant homestead. Cannot version multiple js/css, have to run gulp version --production

Comment: No. same result . Why only one scripts compiling ?